# Using geometry generator to show point and uncertainty

Tags: qgis-3, geometry-generator

I am mapping lightning strikes, my data set contains of, among other things, a point and an uncertainty ellipse. I am storing the data set in a postgis database. The schema for the table is

```
create table lightning (
   timestamp timestamp with time zone not null,
   point geometry(POINT,25833) not null,
   peakcurr integer not null,
   multiplicy integer not null,
   sensors integer not null,
   dof integer not null,
   angle numeric(7,3) not null,
   semimaj numeric(6,3) not null,
   semimin numeric(6,3) not null,
   chi2 numeric(5,3) not null,
   risetime numeric(3,1) not null,
   peak2zerotime numeric(6,2) not null,
   maksror numeric(6,2) not null,
   cloud boolean not null,
   angleind boolean not null,
   signalind boolean not null,
   timingind boolean not null,
   ellipse geometry(POLYGON,25833),
   primary key (timestamp,point)
 );
```

In QGIS it comes up as two different layers:

[image]

I can easily plot either of these layers. For each of them, the other geometry will come up as an attribute. I used to, around September 2021, to be able to plot both of them in one layer using the geometry generator.

[image]

The trickery with the string to array was to get rid of some projection information that was prepended to the WKT. But that stopped working at some point of time, either by an upgrade of postgis or QGIS. I notice when looking into the attribute table, the point attribyte now looks like "Point (276835.35464982531266287 6776668.79492167662829161) [EPSG:25833 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N]". If I copy that text and paste it as the argument for geom_from_wkt, i.e. "geom_from_wkt( 'Point (276835.35464982531266287 6776668.79492167662829161) [EPSG:25833 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N]' )" in the geometry generator, I am told in the expression dialog that I get a point object, and I would assume the same point to be plotted for all the ellipses, but in fact no point is plotted. If I do a geom_from_wkt("point"), I just get a Null, according to the expression generator, also, there the feature is shown as a hexadecimal number like if I do a query directly on the postgis database.

I am a bit stuck, anybody who manages to get it to work to use a geometry stored as an attribute to the main geometry in the geometry generator?

Comment: What if you simply remove  [EPSG:25833 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N] via replace with nothing?