# View a collection of points and multilines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm working on a GIS project and I need to have a representation of the street (which is a multiline) and a group of houses associated with the street.
I managed to group the houses in PostGIS, grouping them by street.
I currently have a table column with 2 geometries:
A multipoint type (for homes)
a multiline down the street.

I tried with ST_Union (geo a , geo b) and correctly I see the merge of the two geometries as a geometry collection.
In QGIS, however, I see them separate.
I can make sure to see Multiline and Points at the same time and not in two separate layers.
I would like to see each street with its houses.

Comment: use the `geometry generator` answer. If it doesn't work, comments from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462156/using-geometry-generator-to-show-point-and-uncertainty) may also help

Comment: I can try. Does the same reasoning also apply to Qgis server? I will have to work with qgis server + Lizmap.

Comment: I also saw the posted post. I couldn't quite figure out how to use it in my case. If someone could help me

Comment: Feel free to edit your post, adding enough information to differentiate it from the duplicate post (i.e. what you have tried, what and how it fails etc)